# Friending template function from multiple classes

Tags: c++, function, oop, friend, friend-function

I have this code:

```
template<typename T> T f() {
// ...
}

class A {
    friend A f();
};

class B {
    friend B f();
};
```

I get `ambiguating new declaration of ‘B f()’` error.

However, if I change my code to following

```
template<typename T> void f(T arg) {
// ...
}

class A {
    friend void f(A);
};

class B {
    friend void f(B);
};
```

program compiles finely.

Could someone help me figure out what is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
friend A f();
```

This line declares that the *non-template* function `A f()` exists and is a friend of the class.  **This is not the same function as `f<A>()` -- it's a completely new function.**

```
friend B f();
```

This line declares another *non-template* function with the same name, but a different return type.  You can't overload on the return type of a function, so this is forbidden.

Neither of these friend declarations refer to your template function, and in your second example the two friend declarations *still* don't refer to the previously-declared template function; they refer to some other non-template function, just like the friend declarations in your first example.

This is probably what you meant:

```
class A {
    friend A f<A>();
};

class B {
    friend B f<B>();
};
```

And, to fix your second example:

```
class A {
    friend void f<A>(A);
};

class B {
    friend void f<B>(B);
};
```